# Get selected checkbox and Ajax post save method for store data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

*i'm facing problem on how to get selected checkbox(single or multiple) and post back to method for save data from modal.*

The function of checkbox javascript is working, so far no idea on how to put them in ajax and post.

Ajax still can't get the data of checkbox while checkbox is clicked!

Here is my modal gridview code for ASPX:

```html
<div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-body">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateGV" runat="server">
               <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:Label CssClass="bolder" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
             <input type="text" name="AddGroup" class="form-control" id="CreateGroup" onblur="GroupCheck()" />
              <br /><br />
               <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvLIST"  CssClass="table table-bordered"  
                 AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
                <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                  <HeaderTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="gvCHECKALL" runat="server" onclick="allCHKBOX(this);"  />
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="gvCHECK" runat="server"  onclick="singleCHKBOX(this)" />
                  </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="ID" runat ="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'  style="display:none"/> 
                 </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="NME"/>
                </Columns>
               </asp:GridView>
               </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
<button id="btnROUPSAVE" runat="server" disabled="disabled" onclick="btnGroupSaveClick()"  > 
   </div>
</div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function singleCHKBOX(chkBOX) {
        var IsChecked = chkBOX.checked;
        var Parent = document.getElementById('gvLIST');
        var chkALL;
        var items = Parent.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var unchkALL = true;
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].id.indexOf('gvCHECKALL') != -1) {
                chkALL = items[i];
                continue;
            }
            if (items[i].type == "checkbox" && items[i].checked == false) {
                unchkALL = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        chkALL.checked = unchkALL;
    }
 
     function allCHKBOX(spanChk) {
        var IsChecked = spanChk.checked;
        var cbxAll = spanChk;
        var Parent = document.getElementById('gvLIST');
        var items = Parent.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].id != cbxAll.id && items[i].type == "checkbox") {
                items[i].checked = IsChecked;
            }
        }
    }
 
</script>
```

```js
function btnGroupSaveClick()
{
    var CreateGroup = $("#CreateGroup").val().trim();
    if (CreateGroup!= "" )
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.aspx/CreateGroup",
            data: "{'CreateGroup':'" + CreateGroup+ "', 'gvCHECK':'" + gvCHECK+ "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
                    
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
                   
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24105652/5743676

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get checkbox checked value inside Gridview using JavaScript / JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052888/how-to-get-checkbox-checked-value-inside-gridview-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @HinaKhuman i have update the question, it might not be the same because i need to get data from modal